# . as a command line argument to a command running in background

Tags: command-line, directory, hard-link

I run `grep some-string -r . &`. While it is running in bkg, I `cd` to another directory. It seems that `grep` interprets the hard link `.` differently then. What happens before and after I change the current directory? Will both the original and the new directories not be searched completely?

I wonder if `.` as a command line argument to a command is only dereferenced at the start of running the command, or is dereferenced whenever it is used by the program during  its running?

Comment: What differences in behaviour do you see?

Comment: it found some files in the original working dir before I changed the working dir, and some files in the new working dir after I changed the working dir.

Comment: Was your new working directory a sub-directory of the initial working directory?

Comment: If it doesn't reveal anything sensitive, would you mind copying and pasting `grep`'s output?

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Not sure why I got the strange result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each process has its own "current working directory", which can't be changed from outside the process.

So when you do

```
grep some-string -r . &
```

your shell starts `grep` in the background, and `grep`'s current working directory is initialised to the same value as the shell's *at that moment*. `grep`'s definition of `.` here is its own current directory, not anything else's; the shell has no part in the argument's interpretation.

Subsequently changing the shell's directory using `cd` has no impact on `grep`...